# Where is mysql bin directory?

Tags: mysql

I have downloaded mysql 5.7 using the windows installer. When I open up the file directory, I cannot find the bin folder. In the past I had used xampp, it had a bin directory. Here is my directory. I need the bin folder to add mysql to the PATH environment variable so that I can work with it from any command line. Thank you in advance.

MySQL
--MySQL Connector Net 6.9.9
--MySQL for Visual studio 1.2.6
--MySQL Installer - Community
--MySQL Notifier 1.1.6
--MySQL Server 5.7
--MySQL Utilities
--MySQL Workbench 6.3 CE

Inside 'MySQL Server 5.7', there is only
--MySQL 5.7 Command Line Client
--MySQL 5.7 Command Line Client Unicode

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just find mysql.exe or mysqld.exe in your system disc (rather C).
Sorry, but i can't check it because of using linux )

Hope it will help you

Comment: Thanks dude! I just did a search for mysqld.exe and sure enough, there it was under another MySQL Server 5.7 folder. Thanks.

Comment: I cant find mysql.exe or mysqld.exe,It seems like the bin folder has been deleted,What should i d now? @Dan